# Containing a defined resource type in Puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to create an instance of a defined resource type (::apt::ppa) that comes before other resources. I am using the [PuppetLabs Apt Module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt).

When adding a new repository via the module, the defined type contains an [exec statement](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt/blob/master/manifests/ppa.pp#L42) that notifies apt::update so that any packages that might be required can be installed correctly. However, when I run my below code, the notify gets scheduled after I attempt to install Java, thereby causing the Java install to fail. I've tried putting anchors around the apt::ppa declaration, but that doesn't help. What else can I do?

```
class rap::java(
  $version = '7',
) {
  $package = "oracle-java${version}-installer"

  apt::ppa { 'ppa:webupd8team/java': } ->
  exec { 'accept-java-license':
    command => "/bin/echo ${package} shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections",
    unless  => "/usr/bin/debconf-show ${package} | grep 'shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1: true'",
  } ->
  class { '::java':
    package      => $package,
    distribution => 'oracle-jre',
  }

  file_line { 'java_environment':
    path => '/etc/environment',
    line => "JAVA_HOME=\"/usr/lib/jvm/java-${version}-oracle\"",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you need to include the apt class within the class you've made to get the ordering right.

This works for me on a new Precise box:

```
class rap::java(
  $version = '7',
) {
  $package = "oracle-java${version}-installer"

  include apt

  apt::ppa { 'ppa:webupd8team/java':
     package_manage => true,
  }

  exec { 'accept-java-license':
    command => "/bin/echo ${package} shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections",
    unless  => "/usr/bin/debconf-show ${package} | grep 'shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1: true'",
  }

  class { '::java':
    package      => $package,
    distribution => 'oracle-jre',
    require => [
      Apt::Ppa['ppa:webupd8team/java'],
      Exec["accept-java-license"],
    ]
  }

  file_line { 'java_environment':
    path => '/etc/environment',
    line => "JAVA_HOME=\"/usr/lib/jvm/java-${version}-oracle\"",
  }
}
```

Log of run:

```
Notice: Compiled catalog for precise64 in environment production in 0.78 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt/File[preferences]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rap::Java/Exec[accept-java-license]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rap::Java/File_line[java_environment]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt/Apt::Setting[conf-update-stamp]/File[/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/15update-stamp]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}0962d70c4ec78bbfa6f3544ae0c41974'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rap::Java/Apt::Ppa[ppa:webupd8team/java]/Package[python-software-properties]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Rap::Java/Apt::Ppa[ppa:webupd8team/java]/Exec[add-apt-repository-ppa:webupd8team/java]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt::Update/Exec[apt_update]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Notice: /Stage[main]/Java/Package[java-common]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Java/Package[java]/ensure: created
Notice: Applied catalog in 39.58 seconds
```

To extend the question further, generally things that are blockers for a standard setup to run are usually moved into a run stage ([documented here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_run_stages.html)).

So I would probably move all of the various repo setup puppet code into pre run stage with other prerequisites (normally you put in repo setup), the run stage will always be run first before the main stage, so you don't have to worry about explictly setting requirements that repos are setup on each package. This makes making changes to repos and prerequisites a lot easier

Comment: The module docs do suggest that you need to declare class `Apt` to use the other facilities of the module, and examination of the code suggests that you do need that class to be evaluated before any `Apt::Ppa`.  I assert, however, that it constitutes a flaw in the module that the defined type does not handle that itself, by doing its own `include 'apt'`.  I'd recommend filing a ticket.

Comment: thanks! that worked. i probably should have read the docs more closely